# Homework user who deletes their questions - what to do?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, homework

A [certain user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/343106/amine) posted a question today, received an answer (from myself), accepted the answer, then deleted the question sometime afterwards. I now find that a very, very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972278/hypothesis-testing-getting-the-wrong-answer) has popped up from the same author. It *seems* as though they are working through a series of homework excercises, are having Math.SE answer their questions, and then deleting the questions to avoid suspicion. Not to mention, users who write answers to these questions are wasting their time because of the deletion. It's not generating Q&A content for the site when it's deleted right after the OP gets their answer...

I don't have the capability to check whether the user has engaged in this behaviour in the past or not, so admittedly I am speculating.

Nonetheless, what's the protocol to deal with this situation? I can find other questions on Meta about users posting homework questions, but nothing about what to do when they are engaging in this deletion behaviour.

Comment: See also [Why do some users delete their questions after receiving an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8528) (And maybe also some discussions [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/8528).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak - Thanks. The answer there says to let a moderator know, so I will do that.

Comment: [The question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1972218/11619) is now undeleted.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - Thank you. Am I imagining that my answer was accepted, or did it become unaccepted in the deletion process or by the user?

Comment: No. Your answer has not been accepted. No checkmark. No upvote as of now.

Comment: I upvoted so that the OP can't delete the question again.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - Right, my mistake. I'm not nearly as concerned about this particular question though as I am about the possibility of this behaviour continuing and wasting other peoples' time. Is there anything reasonable to do to prevent this? Or do we just deal with each question like this individually?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche - Nice idea, cheers.

Comment: What I sometimes do is upvote answers that have zero score if it is the only answer in the question.  I think this prevents the OP from deleting the question.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche - Yep, you're right about that. I read it in the comments of the linked question. It can be hard to anticipate when such action is necessary though. But I suppose that at least a single upvote will be justified by an answer with sufficient effort put into it.

Comment: Re: *Is there anything reasonable to do to prevent this?* I cannot think of some other suggestion how to *notice* such behavior then the ones given at the end of [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/is-there-need-to-patrol-for-deleted-questions).

Comment: To cut the problem at its root, one can also avoid answering questions that smell like homework exercises.

Comment: I tend to flag people like this for moderator attention. It's an abuse of the site and I find it pretty offensive.

Comment: @Did I think that is a bad idea. I am self reading a book and need help with exercises sometimes. I think the risk is worthwhile, after all the harm is just not generating content and perhaps a waste of time. This does not happen very often I think. The questioner of course only thinks this is beneficial; trying and failing exercises graded and correct answer later given is supreme tool of learning. Not every minor problem needs remedies.

Comment: @alireza If you are indeed "self reading a book" and trying to solve the exercises in it, then you most probably have tons of remarks, asides, parallels with other situations, failed tries, whatever, to say about the exercise you are trying to solve when you post a question about it here. If you simply include these in your post, it will definitely not "smell like homework exercises". The phenomenon the present question asks about is quite different and the "harm" it causes to the site is real (if you happen to live in an academic context, just ask around you about the site...).

Comment: I was under the impression that this kind of behavior gradually penalizes the person asking the questions until they can't ask anymore.  So it kind of takes care of itself?  Or was I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Did yes that has been mostly the case but not always for me, you can check my questions and see that I even found a math error in Bott and Tu. But as a matter of principle I am opposed to punitive measures unless the problem is determined to be significant. We should limit "police" action in any community. It must be a minimal. It does not mean we condone the action or we do not advocate remedies by other means. There must always be a determination of significance before broad "police" action is taken. I have a PhD and never found this to be a serious problem. just one data point.

Comment: @Did ps: this includes "community" policing. Answer the questions, unless the problem is determined to be significant maintain honor system. Take no action when in doubt. Do not worry about remedies.

Comment: I would leave a comment. "I'd answer your question, but since you're going to delete it afterward, I won't bother. And who knows, maybe someone else gives you a wrong answer, you copy it down and delete the question from here so no one can let you know that you've been led down the wrong path."

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The exact same thing happened right now to my answer to [this user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/391098/figtree). The post was deleted immediately after receiving an answer (I was still editing). It is very suspicious and I think needs to be checked.

Answer (score 4):

The answer and comment on the first question were totally, misleadingly wrong, and useless to anyone trying to solve the exercise.

That may have played a part in the OP's decision to delete, but in general I think it is a good idea to inform users that

*being unsatisfied (or satisfied) with answers is not a reason for deleting a question.*

Comment: If this is the case, why have you not downvoted my answer? Or anyone else for that matter.

Comment: I consider downvoting on the main site to be unproductive, and don't do it.  @Myridium

Comment: What makes it unproductive? If you are worried about discouragement, I think saying "totally, misleadingly wrong, and useless to anyone" is far worse than a downvote.

Comment: It's unproductive because downvotes are relatively rare and hard to interpret compared to upvotes.  That turns them into a form of noise in the (up minus down) totals.  The criticism of the answer is provided here because the quality of that answer may have played a role in the OP's decision to delete the question and try again with a related post.

Comment: By that logic, refraining from downvoting is going to make the problem *worse*. When an answer is obviously wrong (as you seem to think it is), downvotes do a good job of making everyone aware of this. I've deleted one of my answers previously because the unanimous downvotes made me realise I had made a fatal mistake. I trust the community to respond appropriately, and if the consensus is that my answer is wrong, I will comply and remove it. In this case, there seems to be contention about my answer (upvotes and downvotes) so I'll just leave it.

Comment: Mathematics is not a democracy where correctness is decided by votes.   "Hypothesis testing", the subject and tag of the MSE question, is a specific concept in statistics.  When you write things like "the hypothesis is clearly false" because it fails for one number in the sample, or "*I don't understand why you bothered calculating the mean $\mu$ or the variance* $\sigma^2$. *Please think about what you're doing, rather than plugging in numbers.*"  those are exactly the same as saying that everything you write has nothing to do with hypothesis testing.

Comment: Neither is Mathematics an autocracy where corectedness is determined by one person's interpretation of the question. Refereeing is akin to voting, is it not? Anyway, I think you're right about your assessment of my answer in this case. But your intial method of feedback  (criticism without suggestion) was initially unconstructive. I am trying to help someone, and like everyone I make mistakes. The best thing you can do to let me know is to downvote and leave a comment explaining what the mistake is. A simple "this is wrong" stinks of ego inflation, as it does little to actually help.

Comment: Before your comment was adjusted to explain the mistake, all I was left with was your opinion. Did you not just say that mathematics is not a democracy? Your opinion alone means nothing. Less than nothing when you are not even willing to back it up with a downvote.

Comment: "*The best thing you can do to let me know is to downvote and leave a comment explaining what the mistake is.*".   I left you a comment explaining two of the mistakes, answered your subsequent questions (explaining other mistakes in the process), and did not downvote.  The problem is that you fought the corrections under the question, calling it *my* error of making unfounded assumptions, and are further debating it here.  My opinion, which I did not want to state so bluntly at the time, was that your answer was nonsense that condescended to the OP.

Comment: I think we have very different points of view on the situation. My intention was not to condescend (though I did assume that the OP was a student who did very little research or effort-- turns out I was right. This is a pet hate of mine, so maybe I was a bit mean), and of course I'm going to fight against your suggestions! That's part of natural discourse; I do this to figure out whether I am wrong.

Comment: I do not think my answer is a masterpiece; my focus on this meta question has little to do with the specific instance. If you read the comments here on my question, you will find I care more about preventing others (and myself) from wasting their time in the future. I have little investment in this specific question-- I don't care about **this specific instance**. I care about the process to follow in dealing with people who delete their answers in this manner.

Comment: *"Before your comment was adjusted to explain the mistake, all I was left with was your opinion"*.... Sorry, no.  You were provided with two pieces of information in the original comment (retained as the beginning of the current comment) that were a lot more specific than mere opinion. (1) That the answer was unrelated to the question. (2) That the answer had nothing to do with (hypothesis-testing). That was more informative than a downvote, and was enough hint to browse that tag, look up "hypothesis testing", or open a (statistics) book before contesting the input.

Comment: Alright. On an unrelated note, I have never seen a more divisive answer/question than this one (currently 14 votes either way).

Comment: There was an answer by the User Of Many Names with something like +-30 in both directions and he joked that a "balanced" badge should be awarded for those.

Comment: @Myridium Your answer was blatantly rude. There, I said it. zyx is trying to beat around the bush and be nice about it, but what is basically saying is that the question isn't about proving/disproving a hypothesis. It is about actually using statistics to prove it. Sometimes, obviously wrong hypotheses are used in homework questions to test one's ability to prove/disprove hypotheses.I'll be frank: between the little snippets I see here regarding your answer, and the fact that the OP deleted it...it sounds like you made the person believe they should've never asked their question to begin with.

Comment: As for @zyx not downvoting.... I don't downvote answers I feel are blatantly wrong or rude. I report them, because people should be made aware to take of it, and why would I waste a downvote and lower my reputation on something that needs to be deleted for rudeness?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - I didn't know anyone cared about lowering their reputation from a downvote. It's only 1 or 2 points if I recall correctly. Anyway, I don't really understand what you're saying in your first comment apart from that my answer was rude. And indeed, the OP should never have asked a question with so little effort put into it. That is my sentiment.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - Also, you have more than snippets to go by now. The question has been undeleted in case you want to look.

Comment: @Myridium I'm saying that you answered a question that was in someone's homework and that said homework *required* that they do all the steps of hypothesis testing. I agree, the question was trivial but they weren't allowed to use that fact to skip steps. In other words, your answer was utterly useless as it dodged the question altogether.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - It is unknown what steps the homework question required them to do, because they did not say. I don't know how you can say that steps were skipped when we will never know what (if any) procedure they were *required* to follow. I don't want to bother zyx with these repeated notifications anymore, so if you want to continue this we can do so in a chatroom or you can comment on my question.

Comment: You are welcome to continue auto-notifying me here (if you prefer).  @Myridium

Comment: As far as the "homework" aspect is concerned, the OP wrote out their attempt at a solution, and we know perfectly well what steps were required, as it is part of the definition of Hypothesis Testing in basic statistics courses.   It's odd to keep insisting that despite the tagging as (hypothesis-testing) and (statistics) we are not supposed to know what the problem is about.  It's like a calculus problem tagged (integration) that asks to find an area, it's assumed that will be the method whether or not the problem says "find area by integrating".

Comment: Grown men fighting. *Grabs popcorn*